# How to list all DLLs in my solution and get their version?

Tags: c#, reflection

I've just started using C# and am currently trying to create a class that will compare the version of all dll files with a version string in my database.

However, I am not sure how to get all dll files that belong to my solution. I've tried the following:

```
Assembly[] applicationDLLs = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

I found this on a forum somewhere. But I don't know what using statements are required and if this is valid code at all.

Can any of you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Isn't it easier to keep a version number on your application itself, like in your web.config for example, so you just need to check that number against the version string in the db?

Comment: That would be the easiest way in theory. Hoever, The DLL file version can in some occasions differ from the application version (due to bugfixes etc without rebuilding the complete application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since an *assembly* can contain *several* dlls (`Module`s) you can, technically, try

```
  var result = AppDomain
    .CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(asm => asm.GetModules())
    .Select(module => $"{module.Name,-40} {module.Assembly.GetName().Version}");

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:** (may vary)

```
mscorlib.dll                             4.0.0.0
WFA_Junk_4.exe                           1.0.0.0
System.Windows.Forms.dll                 4.0.0.0
System.dll                               4.0.0.0
System.Drawing.dll                       4.0.0.0
System.Configuration.dll                 4.0.0.0
System.Core.dll                          4.0.0.0
System.Xml.dll                           4.0.0.0
```

However, I doubt if you really want all these `System...` dlls; you, probably, want to check `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` which is *exe* file or alike.

Comment: note that you will get only loaded assemblies from domain and not all assemblies that you have referenced, .net is lazy in loading dlls to memory and does this as late as possible.